# Removing search action when clicked (without action being completed)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a search form, which opens a search field when clicked on search-icon.[image]

So I've turned off the search function so the icon is clickable.

```
var $searchBtn = $search.find('button');
$searchBtn.on('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
```

But now if I return the search function when I've clicked on the search icon

```
$('.icon-search'.on('click', function(e)
{
    $searchBtn.unbind('click');
});
```

I can't click on the cross anymore to close the searchfield because it has got the search function again.

So my question is:

is it possible to put on my `.icon-cross` a `e.preventDefault();` on click without it completing the searchfunction first?

HTML Code:

```
<form method="GET" action="search" class="form-inline">

    <div class="input-group">

        <input type="search" name="query" id="query" class="form-control" placeholder="'Uw zoekopdracht...">
        {/if}">

        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default icon-search" type="submit"></button>
        </span>

    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: please post your html code

Comment: Why are you unbinding click? what is the html?

Comment: @epascarello Because it has to open a form-input first when clicked on first.

Comment: Where is the `x` in the html?

Comment: @epascarello It replaces .icon-search to .icon-close on click (jquery), I use icomoon for the icons so it works with classes

Comment: So do not unbind the event, you should know what state it is in to toggle show or hide. Or use event delegation

Comment: But if I don't do that, clicking on the .icon-search will activate the search function without being able to put something in the input.

Comment: You need to add logic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the same button to do two things. You options are to use two different buttons and toggle their display. No worrying about what code is attached since they are separate.

You can add one click event that can handle both tasks

```
$searchBtn.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass("icon-search")) {
        //search logic
    } else {
       //cross logic
    }
});
```

or you can use event delegation to handle the clicks (which is doing the above check under the covers);

```
$searchBtn.parent()
    .on('click', ".icon-search", function(e) {
        //search logic
    })
    .on('click', ".icon-cross", function(e) {
        //cross logic
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. But when I use the cross logic (closing input and show .icon-show) wouldn't the problem stay? Like clicking on enter when input is filled in, icon-cross won't have the search function only icon that will close the input

Comment: I do not understand the issue... How does clicking enter have anything with clicking the cross? Shouldn't you be handling the enter to cause the search action to fire? Did you try to move the logic into one of the examples and see if it does what you want?

Comment: Thank you, I think I figured it out by using two different buttons.